# Page scroll when interact with tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I am using tabulator 4.7 and I have an annoying issue when I interact with tabulator objects in my page: if I perform whatever operation in a tabulator object on my page my, the page is scrolled to the top.

This occurs when I add a row, when I try to sort a column when I redo a step.

Do you have an idea on how I can avoid this scroll?

This is code of tabulator:

```
articleTable = new Tabulator("#SalesArticlesContainer", {
        layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        responsiveLayout: "collapse",
        height:"100%",
        selectable: "1",
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 20,
        groupBy:"cv_article_code",
        placeholder:"Nessun articolo trovato",
        addRowPos: "top",
        ajaxConfig: {
            method: "POST",
            mode:"cors", //set request mode to cors
            credentials: "same-origin", //send cookies with the request from the matching origin
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json", //tell the server we need JSON back
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", //fix to help some frameworks respond correctly to request
                "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set the character encoding of the request
                "X-CSRF-Token": $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"),
            },
        }, //ajax HTTP request type
        ajaxContentType:"json",
        addRowPos: "top",
        tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
        history:true,
        columns: [
            {formatter:"rowSelection", hozAlign:"center", width:20, headerSort:false, cellClick: function(e, cell) {
                cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
            }},
            {title: "id", field: "id", headerFilter: "input", visible:false},
            {title: "Articolo", field: "cv_article_code", headerFilter: "input", formatter: 'plaintext', width:250, validator:"required", editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true}},
            {title: "Seriale", field: "nr_serial", headerFilter: "input", formatter: 'plaintext', width:120, editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true}, validato: "integer"},
            {title: "Data arrivo", field: "dt_arrival", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "date", sorterParams: {format: "YYYY-MM-DD"}, align:"center", width:130, editor:dateEditor},
            {title: "Data Controllo", field: "dt_control", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "date", sorterParams: {format: "YYYY-MM-DD"}, hozAlign:"center", width:130},
            {title: "Presa pren.", field: "fg_pickup", formatter: 'tickCross', hozAlign:"center", width:30, headerVertical:true},
            {title: "Data presa", field: "dt_pickup", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "date", sorterParams: {format: "YYYY-MM-DD"}, hozAlign:"center", width:130},
            {title: "Spedito", field: "fg_delivered", formatter: 'tickCross', hozAlign:"center", width:30, headerVertical:true},
            {title: "Data spedizione", field: "dt_shipping", headerFilter: "input", sorter: "date", sorterParams: {format: "YYYY-MM-DD"}, hozAlign:"center", width:130},
            {title: "Fatt acquisto", field: "tx_purchase_invoice", headerFilter: "input", formatter: 'plaintext', width: 200, editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true, freetext:true}},
            {title: "Fatt vendita", field: "tx_sales_invoice", headerFilter: "input", formatter: 'plaintext', width: 200, editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true, freetext:true}},
            {title: "Note", field: "tx_note", headerFilter: "input", formatter: 'plaintext'},
            {title: "Nuova", field: "fg_new", formatter: 'tickCross', hozAlign:"center", visible:false},
            {formatter: trashIcon, width:25, hozAlign:"center", cellClick: function(e, cell){alert("Printing row data for: " + cell.getRow().getData().name)}},
            {formatter: closeIcon, width:25, hozAlign:"center", cellClick: function(e, cell){alert("Printing row data for: " + cell.getRow().getData().name)}},
        ],
        cellEdited:function(cell) {
            var rowIndex = cell.getRow().getIndex();
            var edited = articleEditedCells.get(rowIndex);
            if(edited === undefined) edited = 0;
            edited++;
            articleEditedCells.set(rowIndex, edited);
            $('#btnSaveArticles').prop("disabled", false);
            $('#btnUndoArticle').prop("disabled", false);
        },
        historyUndo:function(action, component, data) {
            if(action === 'cellEdit') {
                var rowIndex = component.getRow().getIndex();
                var edited = articleEditedCells.get(rowIndex);
                edited--;

                if (edited ===0 ) articleEditedCells.delete(rowIndex);
                else articleEditedCells.set(rowIndex, edited);
            }
        },
        rowDeselected: function (row) {
            var selectedRows = articleTable.getSelectedRows();

            if (selectedRows.length === 0) {
                hideArticleAdminControls();
                hideArticleControls();
            }
        },
        rowSelected: function (row) {
            $('#txtArticle').val(row.getData().cv_article_code);
            $('#txtSerialNumber').val(row.getData().nr_serial);
            $('#txtNote').val(row.getData().tx_note);
            controlWarehouseButtons(row);
            showArticleAdminControls();
            showArticleControls();
        },
        ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response) {
            $.unblockUI();
            //url - the URL of the request
            //params - the parameters passed with the request
            //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.
            if (response.length === 0) return;
            else if (response.length === undefined) return;
            return response; //return the tableData property of a response json object
        }
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Alessio

Answer (score 1):

I detected the problem: it was the variable height: I switched to fixed height from variable one, now scroll does no longer occur.